# 'Cannot GET /' when debugging express app in vs code

Tags: node.js, express, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get debugging working on VS Code. I have my simple app

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var morgan = require('morgan');

app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(express.static('client'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var lions = [];

app.get('/lions', function(req, res){
  res.json(lions);
});

var port = 3001;
app.listen(port);
console.log('on port ' + port);
```

when I run my server from terminal I get normal output and everything works normally.

```
PS > node .\server\server.js
on port 3001
GET / 200 5.557 ms - 1013
GET /style.css 200 1.908 ms - 10107
GET /app.js 200 2.584 ms - 61761
GET /lions 200 2.785 ms - 2
```

I get served all my files and my app works.

as soon as I try to debug my app (F5), console output is

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe --inspect-brk=15065 api-design-node\server\server.js 
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:15065/9339408e-bf15-475f-8add-767309dc82f5
on port 3001
```

nothing else.

and when I point my browser to localhost:3001 I get

```
Cannot GET /
```

Answer (score 0):

This appens just because you have no route in your express app matching `GET /`, try adding

`app.get('/', (req, res) => res.end('hello'))`

to your code (or try going to `/lions` in your browser).

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi, '/' route should be handled by express.static('client'). at least it works when run manually using 'node server/server.js'.

Comment: but I tried to add what you recommended I get following error in browser:
    TypeError: res.end is not a function its same with res.send()

Answer (score 0):

This code helped me

```
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client")));
```

`path.join` will create absolute path for static file.

Looks like VS code run in different environment